# How should I decide if my func should return optional or implicitly unwrapped optional?

Tags: swift, option-type

If I need to return something that can be nil, how should I decide if my func should return optional or implicitly unwrapped optional? I have seen Swift methods of either version, I am curious what drives the decision to return an optional versus an implicitly unwrapped optional from a function/method because it seems like either way you still need to check for non-nil before you can use it.

For example, SpriteKit's SKNode uses implicitly unwrapped heavily (partial version shown below)

```
class SKNode : UIResponder, NSCopying, NSCoding {

    ...

    /**
     The parent of the node.

     If this is nil the node has not been added to another group and is thus the root node of its own graph.
     */
    var parent: SKNode! { get }

    /**
     The children of this node.

     */
    var children: AnyObject[]! { get }

    /**
     The client assignable name.

     In general, this should be unique among peers in the scene graph.
     */
    var name: String!

    /**
     The scene that the node is currently in.
     */
    var scene: SKScene! { get }

    /**
     Physics body attached to the node, with synchronized scale, rotation, and position
     */
    var physicsBody: SKPhysicsBody!

    /**
     An optional dictionary that can be used to hold user data pretaining to the node. Defaults to nil. 
     */
    var userData: NSMutableDictionary!

    /**
     Kinematic constraints, used in IK solving
     */
    var reachConstraints: SKReachConstraints!

    /**
     Optional array of SKConstraints
     Constraints are evaluated each frame after actions and physics.
     The node's transform will be changed to staisfy the constarint.
     */
    var constraints: AnyObject[]!

    /**
     Sets both the x & y scale

     @param scale the uniform scale to set.
     */
    func setScale(scale: CGFloat)

    /**
     Adds a node as a child node of this node

     The added node must not have a parent.

     @param node the child node to add.
     */
    func addChild(node: SKNode!)

    func insertChild(node: SKNode!, atIndex index: Int)

    func removeChildrenInArray(nodes: AnyObject[]!)
    func removeAllChildren()

    func removeFromParent()

    func childNodeWithName(name: String!) -> SKNode!
    func enumerateChildNodesWithName(name: String!, usingBlock block: ((SKNode!, CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)!)

    /* Returns true if the specified parent is in this node's chain of parents */

    func inParentHierarchy(parent: SKNode!) -> Bool

    func runAction(action: SKAction!)
    func runAction(action: SKAction!, completion block: (() -> Void)!)
    func runAction(action: SKAction!, withKey key: String!)

    func hasActions() -> Bool
    func actionForKey(key: String!) -> SKAction!

    func removeActionForKey(key: String!)
    func removeAllActions()

    func containsPoint(p: CGPoint) -> Bool
    func nodeAtPoint(p: CGPoint) -> SKNode!
    func nodesAtPoint(p: CGPoint) -> AnyObject[]!

    func convertPoint(point: CGPoint, fromNode node: SKNode!) -> CGPoint
    func convertPoint(point: CGPoint, toNode node: SKNode!) -> CGPoint

    /* Returns true if the bounds of this node intersects with the transformed bounds of the other node, otherwise false */

    func intersectsNode(node: SKNode!) -> Bool
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably too early to have strict best practices for swift, but here's my opinion. In general implicitly unwrapped optionals should be used for a few cases such as outlets, properties that are nil until initialization and return values from Objective-C functions, otherwise a regular optional should be used.

If you are creating a function that will return a value or nil, do the other programmers interacting with your code a favor and make the return value an optional.

Comment: I have included code from Apple's SKNode, which uses implicitly unwrapped optional heavily.

Comment: Yeah. All automatically converted objective-c apis return implicitly unwrapped optionals since there is no way of knowing if a function will return nil

Comment: Why not use Optional instead?

Comment: That would work as well. Bu then every time you called an objc method you would have to do unwrapping.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like Swift is a bit too young at the moment for this kind of advice, so take any with a grain of salt. And in the future who knows, maybe a new feature will come to Swift that changes how everyone writes Swift code.

That being said, here are my thoughts on this topic:

In native Swift code you should stay away from implicitly unwrapped optionals as much as you can. If your function may return `nil` for any reason, then the return type should be Optional, which tells the receiver that they can expect `nil` to be returned.

Returning an implicitly unwrapped optional from a native Swift function currently doesn't give you much information. To me it says "This return value should never be `nil`". But in that case, why does it need to be an Optional at all?

**Edit:**
Regarding your posted code, the only reason that code returns implicitly unwrapped optionals is because it is translated from ObjC.

Comment: Implicitly unwrapped optional can still assume a nil value, you just don't need to use ! to force unwrap it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, for old framework the reason apple using implicitly unwrapped optionals is to provide almost the same usage and behaviours as Obj-C.